# $g(x)=\arctan|x|-\text{arccot}|x|$,$f(x)=\frac{[x]}{[x+1]}\left\{x\right\}$,$h(x)=|g(f(x))|$,find domain of $h(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $g(x)=\arctan|x|-\text{arccot}|x|$,$f(x)=\frac{[x]}{[x+1]}\left\{x\right\}$,$h(x)=|g(f(x))|$ where $\left\{x\right\}$ and $[x]$ denotes fractional part and integer part of $x$ respectively,then find the domain of $h(x).$

---

I found the domain of $g(x)$ is $R$(the set of all real numbers).
I found the domain of $f(x)$ is $R-[-1,0)$(the set of all real numbers except the interval $[-1,0)$
Now i am stuck here,and cannot solve further.

Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Mm, why domain of $f$ is $[-1, 0)$?

For example i can calculate $f(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Domain of $f_1(f_2(\ldots f_n(x)\ldots)$ is domain of $f_n(x)$.

In your case domain of $h(x)$ is domain of $f(x)$.

Comment: No Alfred XXX,you are wrong,its domain is $R$.But i dont know what is reason behind that.